# Can't access grub menu no matter what I try | Ubuntu 22.04 | EFI boot

Tags: grub2, uefi, lenovo

I wanna access the grub menu so I can play around with kernel parameters and have them be temporary per boot.

My system is EFI so I tried holding Esc at boot. When I do, it gets frozen at the Lenovo logo. I've also tried setting the following in /etc/default/grub...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=10
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

...and running `sudo update-grub`. That makes the system get stuck at the Lenovo logo for 10 seconds before booting with the Ubuntu logo like normal.

It seems like the Lenovo logo is preventing the grub menu from showing. My laptop is a Thinkpad T440p. How do I get to my grub menu?

Comment: Have you been dual-booting on it recently?

Comment: It is press escape, not hold it. But you may have to press several times as it needs to be after Lenovo logo at start & before grub menu. You may also have an UEFI setting for fast boot that assumes no system changes & immediately boots. That is so fast that you do not have time to press any keys. Check for that setting. You may need to use a full cold boot or total power shutdown to force a normal boot, so then you can press correct key. Grub menu has entry for getting into UEFI. Sometimes just pressing down arrow will cause grub to change from default boot.

Comment: No dual boot, just Ubuntu installed with the default partitions from the installer.

Comment: Pressing Esc rather than holding it doesn't change the behavior. Pressing the down arrow key didn't do anything either. And I can't find a Fast Boot option anywhere in the BIOS. Booting from being completely off doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested in making graphically cool boot menu, and tried a few grub gfxmode options and theme packages, but it only shows Lenovo logo.
So I agree

> It seems like the Lenovo logo is preventing the grub menu from showing.

but I don't know why, I guess gfx problem.

If such is the case, try console mode: `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in `/etc/default/grub`.
It worked fine for my laptop Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E440.

My configutation is

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub | grep -v '^#' | grep -v '^$'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

$ sudo update-grub
```

By this setup, the grub menu shown up on boot.
Typing e key successfully entered into edit mode.

My Reproduction Procedure:

1. Erase whole disc space of /dev/sda and clean install Ubuntu 22.04_1 without network connection.
2. Open the configuration file for edit:

   ```
    $ sudo vi /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. Edit the following three lines like this:

   ```
    GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
    GRUB_TERMINAL=console
   ```
4. Don't forget reconfigure update:

   ```
    $ sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot, worked fine.

Comment: LOL I'm in a bit of a pickle here. Wanted to activate the menu so that I can boot into advanced options and go to recovery mode so that I can use the root console and fix my main user's inability to access sudo (for some reason it broke). But this does work in normal circumstances. :D

Comment: This worked like a charm for stock Ubuntu 22 in VMWare ESXi 8 as well.